# Selector.select() not being unblocked even after I register a channel ready to read from another thread

Tags: java, multithreading, selector, java-nio

I am creating a server to handle many different connections at the same time. I create two `Selector`s, on for the serverSocketChannel to `accept` and then the other for the connections to read data.

The one selector successfully gets past the blocking `select()` function to accept the new connection. Then the goal is to register that SocketChannel that was accepted with the other selector that is currently blocked by it's `select()` function so that I can read the data when I need to.

Everything seems to be set up correctly, but even after sending data, I am not getting past the other selector's `select()` function.

Here is my server file:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Server implements Runnable
{
    
    public Thread threadAccept;
    public Thread threadRead;
    
    protected ServerSocketChannel serverSocket;
    
    protected Selector selectorAccept;
    protected Selector selectorIO;

    protected Set<Connection> connections;
    
    private ByteBuffer buffer;
    
    public Server()
    {
        try
        {
            selectorAccept = Selector.open();
            selectorIO = Selector.open();
            
            serverSocket = ServerSocketChannel.open();
            serverSocket.configureBlocking(false);
            
            InetSocketAddress hostAddress = new InetSocketAddress("localhost",4444);
            serverSocket.bind(hostAddress);
            int ops = serverSocket.validOps();
            SelectionKey selectKey = serverSocket.register(selectorAccept, ops);
            
            
            threadAccept = new Thread(this);
            threadAccept.start();
            
            threadRead = new Thread(this);
            threadRead.start();
            
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error "+e);
        }
    }
    
    public void run()
    {
        if(Thread.currentThread() == threadAccept)
        {
            acceptNewConnections();
        }
        else if(Thread.currentThread() == threadRead)
        {
            readData();
        }
    }
    
    private void acceptNewConnections()
    {
        int numberOfKeys = 0;
        
        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                numberOfKeys = selectorAccept.select();
                Set<SelectionKey> keys = selectorAccept.selectedKeys();
                Iterator<SelectionKey> itr = keys.iterator();
                
                while(itr.hasNext())
                {
                    SelectionKey key = itr.next();
                    if(key.isAcceptable())
                    {
                        SocketChannel client = serverSocket.accept();
                        client.configureBlocking(false);
                        client.register(selectorIO, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
                        System.out.println("New connection");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void readData()
    {
        int numberOfKeys = 0;
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(256);
        
        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                System.out.println("About to block on IO selector");
                numberOfKeys = selectorIO.select();
                System.out.println("I NEVER GET HERE");
                
                Set<SelectionKey> keys = selectorIO.selectedKeys();
                Iterator<SelectionKey> itr = keys.iterator();
                
                while(itr.hasNext())
                {
                    SelectionKey key = itr.next();
                    if(key.isReadable())
                    {
                        SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel)key.channel();
                        channel.read(buffer);
                        
                        String s = buffer.toString();
                        System.out.println(s);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

And here is my main class to kick the server off and also create a client.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Server s = new Server();
        
        
        
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 4444);
                    byte[] data = "hello".getBytes();
                    s.getOutputStream().write(data);
                    s.getOutputStream().flush();
                } catch (UnknownHostException e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that a wakeup would be sufficient

```
client.register(selectorIO, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
selectorIO.wakeup();
```

Or just execute a task on the client thread where it registers the client on the same selectorIO it is waiting for. So the client thread should also check for a task queue as part of its loop (e.g. ConcurrentLinkedQueue) and call a selectorIO.wakup after placing the task in the task queue.

Comment: the              `wakeup()` call was what I was looking for. Thank you